# Strange automatic Hypergeometric2F1 simplification

Tags: special-functions

On [this Wolfram Functions page](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/02/0001/) we can find the following identity:

```
Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, 1] == (Gamma[c] Gamma[c - a - b])/ (Gamma[c - a] Gamma[c - b]) /; Re[c - a - b] > 0
```

In particular, the condition at the end `Re[c - a - b] > 0` restricts the validity of this identity to somewhat specific values of `a,b,c`. Out of curiosity, if we make the following substitution:

```
Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, 1]/.c->1+a
```

> `(Gamma[1 + a] Gamma[1 - b])/Gamma[1 + a - b]`

then we can see an analogous simplification occurring automatically in *Mathematica*.

However, with the above parameter choice it is not guaranteed that the constraint `Re[c - a - b] > 0` is satisfied, since

```
Re[c - a - b]/.c->1+a
```

> `Re[1 - b]`

and the real part of `b`, being completely generic, could possibly be bigger than `1`. Is the simplification done by *Mathematica* still correct? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, in this particular case *Mathematica* makes use of a [different identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/):

```
Hypergeometric2F1[b, a, a + 1, z] == (a Beta[z, a, 1 - b])/z^a
```

This identity is not restricted to any particular parameter values, and in the special case `z = 1` reduces to

```
(a Beta[z, a, 1 - b])/z^a /. z -> 1 // FunctionExpand
```

> `(Gamma[1 + a] Gamma[1 - b])/Gamma[1 + a - b]`

which explains the output.